# Multi-selection with regex (sublime text 2)

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

Is there a way I can enable multi-selection with regex? I don't want to do search and replace, I just want to highlight/select all of the matches according to regex.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 222, accepted):

Sure. Press Ctrl+F, then type your regex pattern and hit Alt+Enter

Comment: Found this very useful. I wonder why ALT+F3 doesn't do the same thing i.e. it works when you mouse select.

Comment: instead of Alt+Enter you can also click 'Find All'

Comment: (of course, regex mode must be on: cmd+alt+r on OSX)

Comment: What about incrementally adding regex matches? If I use Ctrl+D, it replaces the regex with the first concrete match instead.

Comment: This does not seem to work with the "Find in Files" option, just searching an individual file.

Answer (score 1):

You can activate/deactivate the **regex mode** in the search view clicking this icon:

[image]

Note that there is also a shortcut to activate it: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> by default.

Comment: It's `cmd` + `alt` + `R`, not `alt` + `R`.

Comment: I was talking about the Windows shortcut. I don't know what it could be on Mac, but feel free to update my answer :-)